# Solving "no suitable HttpMessageConverter found" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have simple application that is trying consume Rest service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConsumingRestApplication
{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumingRestApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(ConsumingRestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception
    {
        return args -> {
            try
            {
                restTemplate.getForObject("https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
                
            } catch (RestClientException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Quote class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

  private String type;
  private Value value;

  public Quote() {
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public Value getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(Value value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Quote{" +
        "type='" + type + '\'' +
        ", value=" + value +
        '}';
  }
}
```

Got error :

```
org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.example.consumingrest.Quote] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
```

Whole exception trace:

```
2020-10-19 12:39:04.984  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.ConsumingRestApplication           : Starting ConsumingRestApplication on GM with PID 8328 (C:\gdrive\java_test\consumingrest\build\classes\java\main started by g in C:\gdrive\java_test\consumingrest)
2020-10-19 12:39:04.987  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.ConsumingRestApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-10-19 12:39:05.070  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-10-19 12:39:05.070  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-10-19 12:39:06.843  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-10-19 12:39:06.856  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-10-19 12:39:06.857  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-10-19 12:39:06.957  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-10-19 12:39:06.957  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1887 ms
2020-10-19 12:39:07.204  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-10-19 12:39:07.395  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-10-19 12:39:07.603  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-19 12:39:07.617  INFO 8328 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.c.ConsumingRestApplication           : Started ConsumingRestApplication in 3.076 seconds (JVM running for 3.545)
2020-10-19 12:39:07.786  WARN 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.consumingrest.Quote]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize Class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value (of type annotation) as a Bean
2020-10-19 12:39:07.786  WARN 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.consumingrest.Quote]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize Class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value (of type annotation) as a Bean
2020-10-19 12:39:08.541  WARN 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.consumingrest.Quote]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize Class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value (of type annotation) as a Bean
2020-10-19 12:39:08.542  WARN 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.consumingrest.Quote]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize Class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value (of type annotation) as a Bean
2020-10-19 12:39:08.544  WARN 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.consumingrest.Quote]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize Class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value (of type annotation) as a Bean
2020-10-19 12:39:08.545  WARN 8328 --- [  restartedMain] .c.j.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter : Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.example.consumingrest.Quote]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize Class org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value (of type annotation) as a Bean
org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.example.consumingrest.Quote] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:741)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:315)
    at com.example.consumingrest.ConsumingRestApplication.lambda$run$0(ConsumingRestApplication.java:37)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at com.example.consumingrest.ConsumingRestApplication.main(ConsumingRestApplication.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
```

What is starting point o solving this problem?  What logic I should go to find problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are missing `Value` object or must be a wrong import. Along with that you need to add getter methods for the field if they are private, when you are returning that object directly in the response, here is how i have done it:

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @RestController
    public static class Test {

        @Autowired
        private RestTemplate restTemplate;

        @GetMapping
        public Quote test() {
            return restTemplate.getForObject("https://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
        }
    }

    public static class Quote {
        private String type;
        private Value value;
        public String getType() {
            return type;
        }
        public Value getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static class Value {
        private Long id;
        private String quote;
        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public String getQuote() {
            return quote;
        }
    }
}
```